# How to get rows that are last in order within pandas without using a loop

Tags: pandas, train-test-split

I have data that can be grouped by column `type` and then ordered by another column `order`. I would like to know if I can use `sklearn`'s `train_test_split` to split this data such that the rows that have the same value for `order` and are numerically the last, split out as the `test` case. In the example below, I would like the last two rows with `order=3` to go into the `test` case.

| type | order |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |

The way I can think of doing this is programmatically and appending to a list, dataframe or array as I iterate over the `type` after selecting these values first from the bigger dataframe that has multiple types. I am wondering if there's an alternate way of using `train_test_split` or something within `pandas` that avoids a loop.

**EDIT:**

I would also like to have the rows in the top with orders `1` and `2` as I need them in training.

Answer (score 1):

Is the solution below suitable? It filters the rows based on whether they are "order == maximum order value" or not.

[image]

Data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
        'order': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Filter rows

```
top_rows, bottom_rows = [df.loc[rows] for rows
                         in [df.order.ne(df.order.max()), df.order.eq(df.order.max())]
                         ]

display(top_rows, bottom_rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
cond = df.groupby('type')['order'].transform('last').eq(df['order'])
```

`df[cond]`

```
    type    order
4   A       3
5   A       3
```

`df[~cond]`

```
    type    order
0   A       1
1   A       1
2   A       2
3   A       2
```